# EJB Transaction locks / Hibernate isolation levels

Tags: mysql, hibernate, transactions, ejb

I have a webservice that produces a lot of updates in my database. After, it will do some other things (like calculus, call another webservice, etc). At the end, it contacts the database again.

The problem is that the tables are locked during the entire webservice life. So if the "other things" takes longer, I can´t work with the tables for this time.

There is a way to lock just the register, not the tables ?

How can I avoid this situation ?

I´m using Hibernate and MYSQL.

Comment: if you use optimisticlock and do not flush your changes, the table should not be lock. do you use optimisticlock?

Comment: Mehran, i´m using PESSIMISTIC_WRITE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pro JPA 2 book says:

> The reality is that very few applications actually need pessimistic locking, and those > that do only need it for a limited subset of queries. The rule is that if you think
>   you need pessimistic locking, think again. If you are in a situation
>   where you have a very high degree of write concurrency on the same
>   object(s) and the occurrence of optimistic failures is high, then you
>   might need pessimistic locking because the cost of retries can  become
>   so prohibitively expensive that you are better off locking
>   pessimistically . If you absolutely cannot retry your transactions and
>   are willing to sacrifice some amount of scalability for it, this also
>   might lead you to use pessimistic locking.

so I suggest you think again about your need.

> i´m using PESSIMISTIC_WRITE

The hibernate acquires exclusive locks by using ‘SELECT … FOR UPDATE‘ statements(when using pessimistic lock)

> 

4:Connection.TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ lock your selected data(during the transaction). so you do not need to use pessimistic_lock. 
the  pessimistic lock is usually used for repeateabe_read while the transaction isolation is not repeatable_read( when is Read Committed)

following links describe mysql locking mechanism

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html#isolevel_repeatable-read

> There is a way to lock just the register, not the tables?

the selected row should be locked not the tables(  check your selects)

Answer (score 0):

What transaction isolation level are you using? Please refer the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html) to see how this affects locking and how this can be changed.

Check your application. Transactions should be as short as possible. Consider a redesign, if needed. You might even consider using [BASE instead of ACID](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/07/06/brewer-cap-theorem-base/).

Comment: Frito, <property name="hibernate.connection.isolation" value="4"></property>